# if else in javascript leading to missing values

Tags: javascript, json

I have data in JSON format . Follows my JSON string:

```
var dataString4 = {"Details":[{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":98.69999694824219,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature",
"ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic",
"observationValue":66,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,01",
"ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.5,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,02",
"ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":62,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,02","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.4000015258789,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,15","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":65,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,15","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.0999984741211,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,21","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":61,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,21","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":98.5,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":65,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.69999694824219,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,07","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":67,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,07","ReadingType":"Vitals"}]};
```

In above JOSN string , half of the values for Reading name has Heart Rate and rest half Body Temperature.

Then, I have this piece of code to add values:

```
for(var i=0; i<queryObjectLen; i++)
                {
                    //console.log(queryObject.Details[i].DeptName);
                    var ObservationDateTime=  new Date(queryObject.Details[i].ObservationDateTime);
                    var observationValueHeartRate;
                    var observationValueBodyTempearture;
                   var value =  queryObject.Details[i].ReadingName 
                 if(value ='Heart Rate')
                   {  observationValueHeartRate= queryObject.Details[i].observationValue;
                   console.log(ObservationDateTime);
                   console.log("HeartRate" + observationValueHeartRate);
                   }

                  else
                   {
                   observationValueBodyTempearture= queryObject.Details[i].observationValue;
                   console.log(ObservationDateTime);
                   console.log("bodytemp " + observationValueBodyTempearture);
                   }

                     arrdata.addRows([
                        [ObservationDateTime,parseInt(observationValueHeartRate), parseFloat(observationValueBodyTempearture)]
                    ]);
```

**Problem:**  With above statements, I am getting value only for Heart Rate and nothing at all for Body Temperature. What seems wrong in above piece of code ?

Comment: Check out [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), `=` is an assignment operator, try using `==` or `===`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used single "=" sign in if statement.
To compare you need to use "==" in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [Fiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/bw61L7bu/1/)

Im using the open source project jinqJs http://www.jinqJs.com to query your collection.

```
    //Use jsJinq.com open source library
var dataString4 = {
    "Details":[
        {"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":98.69999694824219,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature",
            "ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic",
            "observationValue":66,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,01",
            "ReadingType":"Vitals"},
        {"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.5,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,02",
            "ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":62,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,02","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.4000015258789,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,15","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":65,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,15","ReadingType":"Vitals"},
        {"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.0999984741211,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,21","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":61,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,08,21","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":98.5,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},
    {"ObservationSource":"Outpatient Clinic","observationValue":65,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,01","ReadingType":"Vitals"},
    {"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":98.69999694824219,"ReadingName":"Body Temperature","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,07","ReadingType":"Vitals"},{"ObservationSource":"Patient Self Reported","observationValue":67,"ReadingName":"Heart Rate","ObservationDateTime":"2014,09,07","ReadingType":"Vitals"}]};

var result = jinqJs().from(dataString4.Details).select();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

You can then do a groupBy or use an aggregate function on the result. Let me know if you want anymore examples.